# Installing Dolibarr on Codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter, codeigniter-3

I have a Codeigniter based website and I want to install Dolibarr on the same site. Where is the Dolibarr installation best placed, within the codeigniter folder structure or completely separately at the server root? If within codeigniter then where in the folder structure?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it's too simple juste create under your codeigniter folder same location as "index.php" of codeigniter and next you your a simple installation by calling your dolibarr "install/index.php " file